# pass parameters in react-router-dom Link not woking fine

Tags: reactjs, parameters, hyperlink

I am trying to pass parameters in react-router-dom Link, but not sure why it is not working everytime. sometimes is working fine, some times nothing happened (no error in devtool) when click it.
I have import Link in the beginning, import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pageNumber: 1,
            pageSize: 10,
            keyWork:"",

            // modal: cancel notification 
            visible:false,
            doctorID:"",
            
            // table header
            columns:[
                {title:"Doctor Photo", dataIndex:"picUrl", key:"picUrlMenu", width:70, fixed: 'left',        
                render: picUrl => <Image className="doctorPhoto" style={{ height: 50, width:50 }} alt={picUrl} src={picUrl}/> 
                },
                {title:"DoctorID", dataIndex:"doctorID", key:"doctorIdMenu", width:70, fixed: 'left',responsive: ['md'],
                    defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
                    sorter: (a, b) => a.doctorID - b.doctorID,         
                },
                {title:"Management", dataIndex:"management", key:"management", width:200, fixed: 'right',
                    render:(text, rowData) =>{
                        return(
                            <div>
                                <Button className="planButton" type="primary" icon={<SnippetsOutlined />}>
                                    <Link 
                                        to={{
                                            pathname: "/index/plan", 
                                            state:{doctorid: rowData.doctorID}}}>,
                                        </Link>
                                        Plan
                                </Button>
                            
                                <Popover content={content} >
                                    <Button className="delDoctorButton" icon={<DeleteOutlined />} onClick={()=>this.delDoctor(rowData.doctorID)} >Delete</Button>
                                </Popover>
                            </div>
                        )
                    } 
                }   
            ],

            // tabel data
            data:[],   
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the code did not have problem, now the link only works when click on the text "plan", so if you want to redirect when click the button, just move the Link  to the button, like this: